# How to use Apollo Rover + Codegen to generate typescript schema types

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo

I am struggling to understand how to use [Apollo Rover](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/rover/) in conjunction with [Apollo Codegen](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/tooling/apollo-codegen/typescript-graphql-code-generator-generate-graphql-types/) to generate my typescript types for my API's schema. I registered my schema in apollo studio, and can grab the schema into a GQL file, but it looks like codegen is not supported in the Rover CLI and so I need to use the legacy Apollo CLI. However the Apollo CLI wants schema to be fetched from a remote endpoint and not a registered schema, and wants the schema in JSON format, but Rover only fetches in .gql format.

I'm confused about how I am "supposed" to hook this up so that I can use apollo codegen with my registered schema without a bunch of manual conversion work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this. I think you should keep use Apollo CLI.

[image]

> Rover does not currently provide client-specific features, such as
> code generation or client checks. For these features, continue using
> the Apollo CLI.

Another solution use, it work for me ;)

https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator

Comment: I ended up using this in combination with rover. Basically I registered my schema in apollo studio, created a package script to fetch with rover, and another to generate my types using the [link](https://the-guild.dev/blog/graphql-code-generator)`Guild's` codegen. This seems to work pretty well.